# how to make json object from tree view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jstree

can you please tell me how to make json object  from tree view .I am using jstree.I need to get json object when user "get json " object.

here is my expected out put of my demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/54/

```
[
                        {
                            "id" : "a",

                            "children" : []
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : "b",

                            "children" : [ {"id":"b-a-1", "children" : []}, {"id":"b-a-2", "children" : {"id":"b-b-a", "children" : []},{"id":"b-b-b", "children" : []}}]
                        },

                        {
                            "id" : "c",

                            "children" : [ {"id":"c-a-1", "children" : []}, {"id":"c-b-2", "children" : []}]
                        },
                    ]
```

Comment: So what problem are you having in doing this?

Comment: problem in making json obj

Comment: You mean `JSON.stringify()` isn't working for you? The key challenge is getting the data structure you want it, turning into JSON is a one line task that is very simple.

Comment: yes you are right ..I need to make this structure

Comment: @MikeBrant can you please help me making this structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen [serialize-list plugin](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.serialize-list/blob/master/jquery.serialize-list.js) ?

thank you for downvotes :P

```
function jsonify() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
        id: $this.attr('id'),
        children: $this.find('ul > li').map(jsonify).get()
    };
}

$('#json').click(function(){
    var json_list = $('#tree > ul > li').map(jsonify).get();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json_list));
});
```

this is working for me, but not with that tree plugin, because it changes DOM !

Comment: I need to use plugin ?

Comment: No I never used that plugin

Comment: Your answer should include some actual code relevant to the question at hand. "Link only" answers are frowned upon here.

Comment: @dan do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Dan how to make this structure ?

Comment: I've fixed my answer, so now it's working without your tree plugin, imho you should create some CSS rules and simple jQuery accordion for this, if you want regular JSON to be extracted and have correct ul menu

Comment: another option is to use jstree function get_json, but it generates full js object with all parameters, not only id and children

json_list=$('#tree').jstree(true).get_json();
console.log(JSON.stringify(json_list));